# Do you need to repeat prepositions with two different nouns?

Tags: грамматика

For example, if I was to write:

> Adults remember it with excitement and tenderness.

and to translate it as:

> Взрослые помнят его с волнением и **с** нежностью.

would the inclusion of the 'с' be ungrammatical or not? What would happen with other prepositions (eg Я люблю ходить в музей и ?в? кино.)

Thanks a lot for any help! Большое спасибо!

Comment: I think it's better to translate it as _вспоминают_ ("to call to mind"). _Помнить_ is a state ("to keep in memory").

Comment: Thanks for that

Comment: Related: [Какое правило насчёт повторения предлогов?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420240/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first sentence, it is an example of an anaphora (rhetorical word repetition in the beginning of the phrase).

It is a thing in English as well: "in sickness and in health, in good times and in bad" etc.

It is grammatical. You don't need to use it in this sentence, but you can.

> Взрослые вспоминают его с волнением и с нежностью.

*Волнение* и *нежность* are parts of the same gamut of emotions and they come close in the sentence, so you can omit the preposition.

The second sentence is a little bit different.

> Я люблю ходить в музей и в кино

*В музей* and *в кино* both answer the question *куда?* (not *во что?*) and they are different places.

Compare the two sentences:

> Он заработал состояние на (*чём и чём*?) шкафчиках и тумбочках // He made a fortune on cabinets and nightstands.

"Cabinets and nightstands" can be thought of as a single object with the preposition *на*.

> — Где ключи от машины? — Я не знаю. Посмотри (*где и где*?) на шкафчике и на тумбочке. // "Where are the car keys?" "I don't know. Look on the cabinet and on the nightstand".

Each phrase with *на* answers the question "where" separately. It is stylistically better to add the preposition to every object.